# question closed because a newer question is open

Tags: support

just a got a notification that an old question of mine was closed but I'm confused as to why:

[Windows photo viewer can't run because not enough memory?](https://superuser.com/q/1509194/653198)

apparently closed because it has been associated with a new question - [windows photo viewer can't open picture](https://superuser.com/q/1538377/653198)

However the post it has been associated with is newer, has only 2 answers that aren't upvoted and very little detail throughout.  I have a feeling that the newer post was meant to be closed and not mine?  can someone sort this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### I have a feeling that the newer post was meant to be closed and not mine?

Apologies, you're right - I messed up with the dupe close.

I've fixed it now.

Comment: Although, an older question can be closed, if the newer question receives a better answer. This clearly wasn’t the case but worth mentioning it for any user that doesn’t know that tidily bit.